# How do you remove a film back from a Mamiya 645 Super with no darkslide?

Tags: film, repair, medium-format, mamiya

Just got a Mamiya 645 Super with two film backs but have run into a problem.

The film back attached to the camera is missing the darkslide (so it won't let me remove the back from the camera)

The extra backs I have have the darkslide installed in them (so I can't remove the dark slide w/out it being attached to the camera)

So... How can I either a) remove a film back that has no darkslide on it or b) remove a darkslide w/out it being attached to the camera?

Comment: There must be some sort of release pin/lever that operated the interlock, have a good look at the backs...

Comment: does the 645 have these [tabs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DY28FbNMUg0)?

Comment: @dav1dsm1th Yea the 1st time I loaded that video I was like "Yes, this is it!" then I realized those are different film backs :p

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, there is a *tiny* black button (that looks like a screw) next to the bottom right screw in this photo, that is the button to press to release the slide.  I kept pressing the *giant* button in the upper left thinking that clearly had to be the release :p

[image]